# Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the next issue: Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type hidden to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

My code is the next:

```
import { Container, Grid, Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Store from '../component/store/store'

class StoreBuilder extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {
        DivisionState: 'Store 1',
        DivisionData: [
            {
                id: 1,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                divDeptShrtDesc: 'Store 3'
            }
        ]
    }
    this.renderDivisionOptions = this.renderDivisionOptions.bind(this);
    }


    handleChangeDivision(event) {
        this.setState({ DivisionState: event.target.value });
    }

    renderDivisionOptions() {
        return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem
                    key={i}
                    value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
                    {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {     
        return (
            <div>
                <Container >
                    <Grid >
                    <Store stores={this.state.DivisionState} 
                            onChange={this.handleChangeDivision}
                            render ={this.renderDivisionOptions}>

                    </Store>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default StoreBuilder;
```

The code of the hook is the next:

```
import { Container, Grid, Select, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const store = (props) => {

    return (

        <div>
            <Container >
                <Grid >
                    <Select value={props.DivisionState}
                        onChange={props.handleChangeDivision}
                    >
                        {props.render()}
                    </Select>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );

}
export default store;
```

Any ideas? I understand that it is something related with the state but not pretty sure.

Comment: Honestly, I just ignore the uncontrolled to controlled (and vice versa) errors because it doesn't really break anything. You should probably address it though. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this warning because in the first place `props.DivisionState` is undefined in your `Store` component, then it gets some value. So, uncontrolled input turns into a controlled one. Actually, you don't have a prop named `props.DivisionState`.

You are passing the initial state as `stores` if I am not mistaken. Also, you are passing your changer method as `onChange` but try to use it how you define in the parent. So, there are a few places you should fix in your code. I'm providing a working example, maybe you can change the related parts according to your needs. I've changed a few variables, prop names and define your `handleChangeDivision` method as an arrow one since you need to use `this` there. Also, I think this question is not related to hooks at all.

```
const Store = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Grid>
          <Select value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}>
            {props.render()}
          </Select>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

class StoreBuilder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DivisionState: "Store 1",
      DivisionData: [
        {
          id: 1,
          divDeptShrtDesc: "Store 1"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          divDeptShrtDesc: "Store 2"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          divDeptShrtDesc: "Store 3"
        }
      ]
    };
    this.renderDivisionOptions = this.renderDivisionOptions.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeDivision = event =>
    this.setState({ DivisionState: event.target.value });

  renderDivisionOptions() {
    return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
          {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Grid>
            <Store
              value={this.state.DivisionState}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDivision}
              render={this.renderDivisionOptions}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```